# JQuery .show("slide", 1000) table formatting jumps at beginning and end

Tags: jquery

I am using the `.show("slide", 1000)` method on some unordered list items within a table cell. For seemingly every other effect other than fade, it causes the table to have a different layout **during** the animation than **after** the animation. Any ideas as to why this is happening? As a result it looks pretty glitchy. Any hints to get the layout looking consistent during and after the animation?

http://jsfiddle.net/uuDGj/17/

```
$('li#errorFirstName').show("slide", 1000);
```

Comment: Could you [give us an example](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uuDGj/16/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `slide` does not know how wide your `UL` is, it estimates it as it goes - at least as far as I understand it - and this causes the pixel jumping you're seeing.

I added a width to your `ul` and it solves the jumping issue. Added `ul {width:350px;}` to the CSS window on the top-right of the fiddle.

Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/uuDGj/18/

Ultimately, give elements a width/height so jquery knows what it is before it starts its animation.

Comment: Well, that works, but it really doesn't answer the question why it is happening. I dont buy that jquery doesn't know what width something is.

Comment: It perfectly answers the question. you asked for a hint on getting it consistent, and i showed you how to do it. With regards to the jumpy part,  Just do a search on why jquery is jumpy without element sizes... jquery computes the height/width if it hasn't been set, and it is quite often out by the padding which varies on browser. If this question did indeed help and resolve your issue, please do mark it as answered for other visitors :)

Comment: here is one other example of a similar fix - see the last part of the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375688/fixing-vertical-jump-at-end-of-jquery-slidedown-animation - setting the height of the element to be animated = stopped the jump...

Comment: And another.... http://forum.jquery.com/topic/slidedown-goes-to-far-then-jumps-back - should be enough to prove for now :)

Comment: @RossBarbish, Darren gave you the answer. It has 100% to do with Jquery and width estimation.

Comment: Johannes and Darren sitting in a tree